# Bash: split array of strings into multiple arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script where I get an array of strings (path to files) and want to execute tool and use the values of the array as arguments for the tool. The arguments should not have any flags (no --something ). The size of the array is different on every run, so it can't be hardcoded.

Example:

```
file_array=("/path/1.pcap" "/path/2.pcap" "/path/3.pcap" … )
```

it should execute like this:

```
mergecap -w /path/out.pcap "/path/1.pcap" "/path/2.pcap" "/path/3.pcap" ...
```

*Usage: mergecap [options] -w |-  [ ...]*

I was able to parse that array into a single string with xargs, but then it would take the whole string an use it as single argument.

Thx for your help.

Comment: `"${file_array[@]}"` expands as separate words. Just use this to pass your arguments: `mergecap -w /path/out.pcap "${file_array[@]}"`.

Comment: I spent too much time on this -_-'. Awesome, that one was way too easy. Thank you.

Comment: If you frequently use `bash` its manual (`man bash`) is a bit long but it is really worth reading at least once from end-to-end. You will not remember every detail but at least you'll know where to look for when facing a `bash` problem. And, maybe more important, you'll know that some feature you need exists, even if you don't remember how to use it. Go, spend one our two hours on it, you will not regret. The next time you'll have a question like this one you'll find the answer yourself in minutes if not seconds.